# System ran out of memory during MX Linux installation

Tags: distribution-choice, out-of-memory, mx-linux

```
Hardware specs :
Product Name    HP ProBook 430 G4
Processor 1     Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz (x86)
Memory Size     4096 MB
System BIOS     P85 Ver. 01.03 12/05/2016
Serial Number   5CD7097FPZ
```

[image: memory counter top right corner, at 85%]

I wrote the MX image to removable media i.e
dd if=mxlinux.iso of=/dev/sda status=progress && sudo eject /dev/sda
BIOS finds the media's MBR, which starts GRUB, which boots MX Linux, and without user input consumes my memory in about 2 minutes, then crashes.

Debian suffers from the same issue, at least it doesn't crash until the partitioning step. Linux Mint, and Ubuntu, don't work due to impossible to troubleshoot, random bugs.

I don't want to use Windows, as a last resort a UN*X like OS would be preferable.

What should I do? What OSes should I try?

Comment: Restart it in console mode without running a gui and see how far it gets. Try some of the more mainstream images as well.

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked yesterday?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I'm new to stackexchange. I revised it, no one answered then I replaced it.
Whats the problem?

Comment: Reposting due to not receiving enough attention is a form of spam. If you do it to "cancel" downvotes, then you are actively circumventing the voting system, which is not allowed. Note that you would bump the question to the top automatically by editing it, and adding more information to a question may be preferred to giving up on it, deleting it, and posting it again with pretty much the same text. Deleting too many of one's questions may also trigger automatic banning rules, or alert us moderators about possible vandalism.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: Ok. It did not receive downvotes. I read the rules on deleting, and I should edit next time instead :
https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question :
"**If nobody has answered yet, go ahead and delete it nobody minds.**"

Comment: I'd consider using (as root) sync(1) instead of eject. Maybe the eject didn't flush the write buffers, which sync is guaranteed to do. You can check which process "consumes the memory in about 2 minutes" with top(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think HP doesn't play well with Linux :
https://www.quora.com/Which-laptop-is-a-better-option-for-running-Linux-Dell-HP-or-Lenovo

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Can-t-install-ubuntu-on-HP-probook-440-G4/td-p/6933204

I sync and eject the media, verified my downloads, even so any distro I try crashes : Debian, Fedora, Gentoo, but they work with my Lenovo (x86 also) pc.

Comment: This is an interesting statement given links like [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/09/buy-hp-zbook-fury-with-ubuntu) and [this](https://linuxhint.com/best_10_laptops_linux/). I've had no problems with HP and Linux and run my Linux datacenter on HPE servers.

Comment: It would be better to [edit] and include the relevant details from the links, in case of link-rot. Otherwise this is a bit of a link only answer.